# How to download an Excel file that has been opened by Google Sheets?

Tags: excel, google-drive-api

I've been running into issues when downloading Excel .xlsx files using Google Drive Api v3. The code I'm using is as follows (I'm using [the .NET SDK](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client)):

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DriveQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
        static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";

        const string FileId = "my_file_id"; //put the ID of the Excel file you want to download here

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Run().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.Read();

        }

        private static async Task Run()
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Drive API service.
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            FilesResource.GetRequest getRequest = service.Files.Get(FileId);

            using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("anExcelFile.xlsx", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                var downloadProgress = await getRequest.DownloadAsync(stream, CancellationToken.None);
                if (downloadProgress.Exception != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("We got error {0} {1} {2}", downloadProgress.Exception.Message, Environment.NewLine, downloadProgress.Exception.StackTrace));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Download ok");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can run this sample easily by following the steps described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet). This works fine, however, as soon as someone opens the file with Google Sheets and modifies it, I start seeing the following error

```
D2020-03-16 02:10:13.647293 Response[00000007] Response status: InternalServerError 'Internal Server Error'
D2020-03-16 02:10:13.653278 Response[00000007] An abnormal response wasn't handled. Status code is InternalServerError
D2020-03-16 02:10:13.660288 Response[00000007] Abnormal response is being returned. Status Code is InternalServerError
E2020-03-16 02:10:13.667240 Exception occurred while downloading media The service drive has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Internal Server Error
   at Google.Apis.Download.MediaDownloader.<DownloadCoreAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
```

Looking at the file info after it was open with Google sheets, I can see that its size is changed to 0, so I tried to export it as you would for a Google spreadsheet, like so:

```
FilesResource.ExportRequest exportRequest = client.Files.Export(fileId, mimeType);

using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    await exportRequest.DownloadAsync(stream, cancellationToken);
}
```

With mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

However, I then run in the following error:

```
D2020-03-16 01:53:13.512928 Response[00000003] Response status: Forbidden 'Forbidden'
D2020-03-16 01:53:13.520906 Response[00000003] An abnormal response wasn't handled. Status code is Forbidden
D2020-03-16 01:53:13.525911 Response[00000003] Abnormal response is being returned. Status Code is Forbidden
E2020-03-16 01:53:13.538857 Exception occurred while downloading media The service drive has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Export only supports Google Docs. [403]
Errors [
    Message[Export only supports Google Docs.] Location[ - ] Reason[fileNotExportable] Domain[global]
]

   at Google.Apis.Download.MediaDownloader.<DownloadCoreAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
```

So it seems that neither downloading nor exporting is working in this particular case. Anything else I should be trying ? Using the webContentLink (https://drive.google.com/uc?id=fileId&export=download) works fine (in a browser that is) so I guess it should be possible to download the file.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, please let me know the solution in case you manage to fix it!

Comment: Hi @AntoineChaussin! After reviewing and duplicating your code, it is not clear for me if this behaviour comes from the code itself or the API. To prevent missing any important detail, could you please share the minimal complete code that reproduces this issue? Please, obscure or delete any private identifiable information on the script before posting it. And finally, I am also curious to know if you tested this subject in a browser with just one or multiple Google users logged in, could you clarificate it to me?

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron, can you take a look into my code?

The code below works but only for native Google Sheets files: 
`var request = service.Files.Export(fileId, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        downloadProgress = request.DownloadWithStatus(stream);`

And the following code works till the files are opened and edited with Google Sheets. Although, I am almost 100% it was working 2 weeks ago
`var request = service.Files.Get(fileId);
downloadProgress = request.DownloadWithStatus(stream);`

Comment: Hello @Jacques-GuzelHeron ! I've edited the post to have an executable sample. To reproduce, upload an Excel file on Google drive (you can run the sample then to confirm that it works as expected), then open the file with Google sheets, modify it, close the GSheet tab, and run the sample again. You'll get an error. Please also note that this can be reproduce in OAuth playground so I doubt the .NET code is the issue here.

Comment: I've opened a bounty on this one! Really need an urgent solution -.-'

Comment: Hello there @AntoineChaussin and @JoãoTeixeira! I used the posted code to reproduce the error and followed every one of your steps, but I couldn't get the same error. I can download and open the edited .XLSX without issue. Does this behaviour occurs with every .XLSX? If not, please share a spreadsheet that triggers the error so I can reproduce it.

Comment: Hi @Jacques-GuzelHeron, the steps are: 1) Upload an XLSX file; 2) Open with Google Sheets and close it; 3) Try to download. I've also noticed that after doing this, when you double click to preview on google drive an error occurs. File example -> [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ac58iNpyKpEf-kN1IP3M8502AkSObsDz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I raised the issue to Google and it seems it was fixed (cf [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151655367)). I tried again today and following the steps described in the original question, I now can see that after the Excel file has been edited with Google sheets, its size is now greater than 0 and it can be downloaded.

Files that couldn't be downloaded because of this issue still appear to have the same problem but deleting/reuploading manually these files should make them downloadable.